# Parse geo query is always empty

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-parsequeryadapter

I'm working on an Android app that, among other features, detects places in the user's proximity. For this, I use a Parse Query based on the example from the [Anywall app](https://parse.com/tutorials/anywall-android). The problem is that the result of this query is always empty, even though my database is populated. Here is my code:

```
private static final int MAX_SEARCH_DISTANCE = 150;
private static final int MAX_SEARCH_LIMIT = 10;
ParseGeoPoint userLocation = new ParseGeoPoint(Double.valueOf("23.0465320"), Double.valueOf("72.5925700"));
ParseQuery<VevantoParse> mapQuery = VevantoParse.getQuery();
mapQuery.whereWithinKilometers("location", userLocation, MAX_SEARCH_DISTANCE);
```

And the class that extends ParseObject is:

```
@ParseClassName("Posts")
public class VevantoParse extends ParseObject {

public static ParseQuery<VevantoParse> getQuery() {
    return ParseQuery.getQuery(VevantoParse.class);
}
}
```

I don't understand one thing: the "location" key. How does Parse know how to associate that key with my class in the cloud? In all the examples I've read, "location" is used as a key, but I don't understand the logic. Is there something that I have to set in the Parse dashboard? Each place in my database has a latitude and longitude. They were String at first; I changed them to Double, but it still didn't work.

I have also tried using a query that does not depend on my VevantoParse class:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> getPlacesQuery =            ParseQuery.getQuery("my_class_name");
ParseGeoPoint userLocation = new ParseGeoPoint(Double.valueOf("23.0465320"),    Double.valueOf("72.5925700"));
getPlacesQuery.whereWithinKilometers("location", userLocation,    MAX_SEARCH_DISTANCE);
```

But to no use. Note that the query works when I place conditions not related to location, like whereEqualTo. Can you shed some light on the problem, please? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Narcis

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you should pass the class name (as String) to the `ParseQuery`:

```
public static ParseQuery<VevantoParse> getQuery() {
    return ParseQuery.getQuery("VevantoParse"); // where VevantoParse is your Parse's class name
}
```

Here is the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html).

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your answer. I have tried the solution you suggested, but it didn't work. As an extra, I renamed the class in my app (VevantoParse) to VevantoCloud, which is the name of the object that stores the data in the cloud. But that didn't work either...

Comment: Don;t know what to say. Worked for me... Follow the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody interested, the problem is that I didn't define a Parse Geo Point in my server database. To do this, when you add a row into the database (I did it from my Java code), you simply define a Parse Geo Point named using a key ("location" in my case), and then you add the condition
    mapQuery.whereWithinKilometers("location", userLocation, MAX_SEARCH_DISTANCE);
using that certain key.

Good luck!